# view does not resize even after implementing shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

for my code,
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is getting called and i am returning YES there but still when I rotate the device, controller's view change its size but a UIImageView inside the main view does not change its size. I want it to be resized just like the main view.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the `autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` according to your need.

In code

```
imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,40,120,100)];
imageview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

If you have created in xib then in IB set
 this as shown in the below image
[image]

Comment: where you have created this in IB or in coding??

Comment: from code.. imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,40,120,100)];

Comment: many thanks. i added the line in code "autoresizingMask" and it is working...!!